# Show if restaurant is open or not in current time and day

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have two model one for restaurant and another for operating time. Operating time has foreign key relation with restaurant as operating time might be different in different days in a week. I wanted to show if the restaurant is open or closed in current time and in the current day. Will it be better to code this in views.py or create a template tag for this? Because the convention says views should be thin.

**models for restaurant and operating time are**

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class OperatingTime(models.Model):
    MONDAY = 1
    TUESDAY = 2
    WEDNESDAY = 3
    THURSDAY = 4
    FRIDAY = 5
    SATURDAY = 6
    SUNDAY = 7

    DAY_IN_A_WEEK = (
        (MONDAY, 'Monday'),
        (TUESDAY, 'Tuesday'),
        (WEDNESDAY, 'Wednesday'),
        (THURSDAY, 'Thursday'),
        (FRIDAY, 'Friday'),
        (SATURDAY, 'Saturday'),
        (SUNDAY, 'Sunday'),
        )
    # HOURS = [(i, i) for i in range(1, 25)]
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant,related_name="operating_time")
    opening_time = models.TimeField()
    closing_time = models.TimeField()
    day_of_week = models.IntegerField(choices=DAY_IN_A_WEEK)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} ---- {}'.format(self.opening_time, self.closing_time)
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    restaurant = Restaurant.objects.all()
    print('restaurant',restaurant)
    operating_time = OperatingTime.objects.all()
    print('operating time',operating_time)
    for operating_time in operating_time: # Tried to find if restaurant is opened or closed based on opening time & closing time in current time and day for each restaurant
        opening = operating_time.opening_time
        closing = operating_time.closing_time
        print('opening',opening)
    current_time = datetime.now()
    current_time = current_time.time()
    if current_time < closing or opening< current_time:
        print('opening')
    else:
        print('closed')
    return render(request, 'restaurant/homepage.html', {'restaurant':restaurant})
```

**How can i find this ? Is it better to code on views or create template tag?**

Comment: Why not put it on the model, as a property?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Which one is preferred as best practice? Calculation in models or create custom template tag?

Comment: IMO it's not worth extracting a template tag unless it will be used with multiple models/attributes. Also: you have just made your question internally inconsistent and invalidated the existing answer, so I rolled it back.

Comment: Sorry i am a new one. I did not know about that. I apologize for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with django at my work place for about a month now and have been taught to not put any logic into the views. The view should be only to pass on the data from the database or post data to the database. The logic should be done in template tags.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have checked for each restaurant based on the current time but how can i check if restaurant is open or close based on the day too ? Because each day has different opening and closing time.

Comment: You could use datetime.datetime.today.weekday() which returns the day were 0 is Monday and 6 is Sunday.